# Is someone using Business intelligence with Cassandra database?

Tags: cassandra, reporting, business-intelligence, apache-superset

We store timeseries operational data in Cassandra. Currently Cassandra table powers the user interface and works fine. About 300K/Minute records are inserted with retention of 2 months. We would like to use Business Intelligence (BI) tool like Apache Superset to connect with the database so that reports/dashboards can be created. We do not have Apache Spark or Presto in the tech stack.

The BI tools likes to speak SQL. In Cassandra you need to know the queries in advance to design your schema. You need to duplicate the data in various combinations. Being a noSQL database, it looks like it is not fit for ad-Hoc analytics provided by BI tools.

- Are you using Cassandra for such use cases and how?
- What is the alternative if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Superset requires a SQLAlchemy driver to work with a database like Cassandra. In general, I recommend Superset enthusiasts who want to query NoSQL databases use an intermediate query engine like Presto, Trino, or Drill

- https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/cassandra.html
- https://preset.io/blog/2021-6-22-trino-superset/

Answer (score 1):

Only in limited-to-Cassandra use cases as set out here https://dzone.com/articles/an-introduction-to-apache-cassandra.

Lack of join and sub queries etc. make things difficult.

Unloading to AWS Timestream, Snowflake, Kudu et al is advisable.